# Puzzling error in svyby of survey package

Tags: r, survey

I am using "svyby" function from `survey` R package, and get an error I don't know how to deal with. 
At first, I used variable *cntry* as a grouping, next, I used *essround* as grouping, and it all worked smoothly. But when I use their combination *~cntry+essround* it returns an error.

I am puzzled how it can work separately for each grouping but doesn't work for combined grouping.

This is somehow related to omitted data, as when I drop all the empty cells (i.e. using *na.omit(dat)* instead of *dat* for defining survey design) it starts working. But I don't want to drop all the missings. I thought na.rm argument of svymean should deal with it. Note that variables *cntry* and *essround* do not contain any missing values.

```
library("survey")
s.w <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = dat, weights = dat[,weight]) 

svyby(~ Security, by=~ essround,       s.w, svymean, na.rm=T) # Works
svyby(~ Security, by=~ cntry,          s.w, svymean, na.rm=T) # Also works
svyby(~ Security, by=~ essround+cntry, s.w, svymean, na.rm=T) # Gives an error

Error in tapply(1:NROW(x), list(factor(strata)), function(index) { : 
  arguments must have same length
```

So my question is - how to make it work?

**UPDATE.** 
Sorry, I misread the documentation. The problem is solved by adding `na.rm.all = TRUE` to the `svyby` function.

Comment: I'd try: `by=~ interaction(essround,cntry)`

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for the late answer, but I was just looking for solution for a similar problem and solved it for myself just now. Check to see if you have any empty cells in your cross-tabulation of `essround`, `cntry`, and `Security` (using `table()`). If you do, try transforming the grouping variables into ordered factors with `ordered()` and explicitly naming your levels with the `levels` argument of the function, before you run the `svyby()`. Ordered factors will show frequency of 0 in a cross tabulation, while regular factors will drop empty cells.

Comment: I tried it but get the same error :( 

`dat$cntry.o        <-   ordered(dat$cntry, levels=unique(dat$cntry))
dat$essround.o <-   ordered(dat$essround, levels=unique(dat$essround))

s.w <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = dat, weights = dat[,weight]) 

svyby(~ Security, by=~ essround.o+cntry.o, s.w, svymean, na.rm=T)`

Comment: @Maksim What type of variable is `Security`? When I was solving a similar issue for myself, I was trying to apply `svymean` to a factor (call it `X`), disaggregated by two other variables via `svyby`, in order to get the percentage of cases for each level of `X`. So in my case I also had to make `X` an ordered factor too. But if you just want the disaggregated mean of `Security`, this wouldn't be the same for you

Comment: In general, I don't think it's a good idea to store continuous variable as a factor, ordered or not. (I assume your X is continuous as you compute its mean). BTW, the solution for my case was just adding `na.rm.all = TRUE` to the `svyby` function

Comment: @Maksim Yes you're right; I meant in my case my `X` was categorical so storing it as a factor was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but here's how I resolved the same issue. It seems to have something to do with the way `svyby` deals with `NA` data - even if you specify `na.rm=T`. I made subsets of my data frame and found that it does happen if the subset is smaller than the certain threshold (it was 500 in my case, but the exact value is to be determined) AND contains `NA` - works well for other subsets like bigger than 10,000 with `NA` or smaller than 500 without `NA`. In your case, there should be a subset of `essround==x & cntry==y` which is small and where `Security = NA`. So, clean the data not to have `NA` BEFORE you do `svyby` (could be removal, estimate, or separate grouping - it's up to you) and then try once again. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but as i said, I don't want to remove all the NAs listwise - my dataset contains many variables and listwise deletion would mean removing more than 50% cases, which is not acceptable. I could delete NAs pairwise manually, and make svydesigns for each pair of variables manually, but it is very tedious and time consuming.